# Save map zoom and location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app that uses the google map, and I am looking for a way to save the location that the user is currently at so that when they bring the app back up they will be right back where they left off. I have searched the internet and I guess I am not searching with the right keywords, or maybe it can't be done in the way I was hoping to do it.

Comment: Another alternative would be to find a way to grab the current focus point on the map and save it in shared preferences, but I don't know how to get the location from the map without them clicking on it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it in `SharedPreferences`, save the latitude as a double save the longitude as a double and save the zoom level as an int

Comment: Is there a way to grab the location of the center of the map at a given time?

Comment: I think its something like `map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter();` but I am not 100% sure on that

Comment: Assuming you are using Maps API v2, you can do `map.getCameraPosition()` to have access to all of the pertinent details like map center (target), zoom, etc. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getCameraPosition()

Comment: ahh yes the camera position one is the better one to use since its gives you the exact center of what you are looking at where as getCenter() just gives you an average center